# Validate Entity Framework Model classes

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have a Model `Supplier` which is generated by `EntityFramework` database first approach .  I wrapped this in my `ViewModel` `SupplierViewModel`, which enables it to  be easily displayed and edited by a WPF user interface. Here is my Model:

```
public partial class Supplier:IDataErrorInfo
{
    public Supplier()
    {
        this.TblPurchases = new HashSet<TblPurchase>();
        this.TblPurchaseOrders = new HashSet<TblPurchaseOrder>();
        this.TblSupplierAddresses = new HashSet<TblSupplierAddress>();
    }

    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TblPurchase> TblPurchases { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TblPurchaseOrder> TblPurchaseOrders { get; set; }
    public virtual TblUser TblUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TblSupplierAddress> TblSupplierAddresses { get; set; }
    public virtual TblCompany TblCompany { get; set; }

    #region IDataErrorInfo members

    //Validation logic put here

    #endregion 

}
```

I put validation logic in this model class by using `IDataErrorInfo`.  My problem is when I generate the model classes from the database using the `Entity Framework wizard` I lost the changes (`IDataErrorInfo`) .  Why I lost the changes ?  Then how do I validate my model classes here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes were lost because the auto-generating wizard is recreating these classes from scratch.

The best way to get around this is to create another partial class in some other folder. Perhaps call the folder IDataErrorInfoPartials or something meaningful. Then create your classes like this:

```
public partial class Supplier:IDataErrorInfo
{   
     #region IDataErrorInfo members

     //Validation logic put here

    #endregion 
 }
```

The compiler will then combine these into one class.

I think you would need to make sure both partials occupy the same namespace too.

[Here is a link about partial classes.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/wa80x488.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Database First, your model classes are auto generated classes which refer to the table of the database. So when you generate model classes from the database it will create properties for all the fields and relationships that are in the table. Your error info detail is not part of the table so it would obviously not there when you generate new one.

You can either use partial classes or DTO classes for adding the validation logic. Do not modify auto generated classes.